# Whether offline maps are charged by Mau, tile requests, or both

Tags: mapbox

In Map_SDK_V6, you can see that it is charged according to the tile requests, but there is no charging content in v10. Is it cancelled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your offline tile usage will be billed as Vector Tiles API or Raster Tiles API requests.

According to the following paragraph, the Mapbox SDK includes Mapbox SDK contains vector Tiles API.

Which Mapbox services are included?
Maps SDK MAUs cover any use of the Vector Tiles API and Raster Tiles API in an application that includes the Maps SDK with no upfront commitments or annual contracts. These APIs are used, for example, when displaying a map view and panning around the map.